# Laravel group by id, sum qty and group date to month and year request only and get count

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to make data based on 2 groups. namely the month group in that year and the group id then calculated based on the existing product id of the product in

I tried this code

```
$tahunx = '2021';        
          $barangmasuk=BarangMasuk::groupBy('id_barang','months')->select([
                'barang_masuk.id_barang',
                DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(tgl_masuk,'%M %Y') as months", '=',$tahunx),
                DB::raw('sum(jml_bm) as jumlah')
            ])->get();
    
            dd($barangmasuk);
```

I want to create data that looks like this

there is table 1 and table 2 that I use

I have given it but this is the result, for group by id_barang it can, but grouped according to the month does not get the result

```
    Collection {#862 ▼
  #items: array:7 [▼
    0 => BarangMasuk {#854 ▼
      #table: "barang_masuk"
      #fillable: array:4 [▶]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:3 [▼
        "id_barang" => 1
        "months" => "April 2021"
        "jumlah" => "100"
      ]
      #original: array:3 [▼
        "id_barang" => 1
        "months" => "April 2021"
        "jumlah" => "100"
      ]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
    1 => BarangMasuk {#855 ▶}
    2 => BarangMasuk {#856 ▶}
    3 => BarangMasuk {#857 ▶}
    4 => BarangMasuk {#858 ▶}
    5 => BarangMasuk {#859 ▶}
    6 => BarangMasuk {#860 ▶}
  ]
}
```

the result is double id and month data

Then this is an example of the table that I use

Tabel barang

```
+-----+-------------+---------+
| id  | nama_barang | stok    |
+-----+-------------+---------+
| 1   | Sayur       | 10      |  
| 2   | daging      | 50      |   
| 3   | Buah        | 20      |      
+-----+-------------+---------+
```

Tabel barang masuk

```
+-----+-------------+-----------+---------+
| id  | tgl_masuk   | id_barang | jml_bm  |
+-----+-------------+-----------+---------+
| 1   | 25-05-2021  | 1         |   200   |
| 2   | 25-05-2021  | 2         |   100   |
| 3   | 25-05-2021  | 1         |   100   |
| 4   | 25-05-2021  | 1         |   200   |
| 5   | 25-05-2021  | 2         |   100   |
| 6   | 25-05-2021  | 1         |   100   |
| 7   | 25-04-2021  | 1         |   300   |
| 8   | 25-04-2021  | 2         |   200   |
| 9   | 25-04-2021  | 2         |   100   |
| 10  | 25-04-2021  | 1         |   200   |
| 11  | 25-04-2021  | 3         |   100   |
| 12  | 25-04-2021  | 3         |   100   |
+-----+-------------+-----------+---------+
```

In order to get results like this

```
+-------------+------------+-----------+
| tgl_masuk   | id_barang  | sum(jml_bm|
+-------------+------------+-----------+
| April-2021  | 1          |      500  |
| April-2021  | 2          |      300  |
| April-2021  | 3          |      200  |
| Mei-2021    | 1          |      600  |
| Mei-2021    | 2          |      200  |
+-------------+------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Your tried the code but what happen? Is there any error? If there's no error, does the result return not according to what you want? [Please edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67679811/edit) and include error (if any) or the incorrect results and your `table 1` and `table 2` data sample. And please post in textual format and don't post them as photos.

Comment: The results don't match, sir, I've edited and included the example table barang and the barang_masuk table above. Is there something missing in my code and the placement is wrong, please guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In plain MySQL query, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(tgl_masuk,'%M-%Y') AS 'DY', id_barang, SUM(jml_bm) AS 'Jumlah'
  FROM barang_masuk
  WHERE YEAR(tgl_masuk)='2021'
GROUP BY DY, id_barang
ORDER BY DY, id_barang;
```

Although I'm not sure how to convert this query to laravel/eloquent.

[**Demo fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=10623042229dbcf723f3418b587ba9f2)

Comment: thank you for the input. I have converted it to laravel and the results are what I want